# Convert font in WOFF2 format to something else

Tags: fonts, webfonts, woff2

My team has a woff2 font file, which we are not equipped to deal with. Does anyone know a pipeline for downgrading to a more common format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://github.com/google/woff2

This project provides woff2_decompress, which converts your woff2 to ttf.

With ttf you can convert it to all webfonts:

- woff, svg, otf can be converted with fontforge
- eot can be converted with ttf2eot

Comment: this was the ONLY tool that worked where all the other popular web alternatives failed on my woff file with an "invalid format" error... also i can confirm Windows users can finally join all the FOSS fun - recently released Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Bash shell on Windows 10 successfully compiled this source... once you've got bash running you need to "sudo apt-get install git" "... make" and "... g++" prior to executing the build instructions in the github readme

Answer (score 5):

https://onlinefontconverter.com is a free online tool to convert almost any font anything else. It supports downgrading woff2. And you don't have to install any program

Comment: [It appears](https://github.com/jimmywarting/ofc) you are affiliated with onlinefontconverter.com. Please note that our [self-promotion policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497) requires you to disclose this information in answers like this one.

Comment: Also, it appears that the service isn't producing proper ZIP file - getting CRC fails all over the show.

Comment: The service is perfectly working to convert woff2 to ttf. And it's totally free. The users with a bigger heart can respectfully donate something to the developer.

For your peace of mind, I am not the owner/promoter, but I found it mentioned by someone on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45690/how-to-convert-a-woff2-webfont-into-a-ttf-desktop-font/.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote
https://my-font-converter.vercel.app/
for converting between ttf and woff2.

It's based on google's woff2 lib, and also Open Source: https://github.com/LibreService/my_font_converter.

Your font is not uploaded to a server. Conversion happens in browser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).